# Using UserTransaction in concurrent threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, oracle-sqldeveloper

On JBOSS 6 I'm doing some testing for a method that connects to an SQL database and update some tables. Now I want to execute this method but in multiple threads in order to increase the performance.

So I want to do something like this:

First I have the thread class:

```
class TransactionThread extends Thread {
    UserTransaction userTransaction = app.getUserTransaction();

    @Override
    public void run() {
      userTransaction.begin();
      //TRANSACTION CODE
      userTransaction.commit(); 
    }
}
```

Then I want to create and execute some threads:

```
ArrayList <TransactionThread> threadList = new ArrayList<TransactionThread>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     threadList.add(new TransactionThread());
}
for (TransactionThread item: threadList ){
     item.start();
}
```

Now the problem here is that since this method is being executed concurrently. If any of the threads finish its transaction and commits the threads that are still running will also commit and the connection to the database will close.

Getting this error:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

What can I do in order to avoid the connections being closed and keep the method being concurrent?

EDIT: this is what `app.getUserTransaction()` does:

```
public UserTransaction getUserTransaction() {
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        return (UserTransaction) context
                .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem that you are describing is actually what is happening. I am not too familiar with sql connections but it seems to me that each transaction thread has its own user transaction. So how do the other threads know if another thread's user transaction has committed? Unless app.getUserTransaction() returns the same object everytime you call it?

Comment: Also, rather than managing your own threads using an arraylist of threads - I suggest you use ExecutorService (thread pool). Here is a bit more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: @Steven I put in the question what app.getUserTransaction() returns and the same object is being called in all the threads. Also thanks for the help I'm very new to jboss and multithreading transactions so sorry if any questions that I do here are dumb.

Comment: It looks to me that app.getUserTransaction() returns a new UserTransaction object (since your context object is declared new). Correct me if I am wrong (I am not familiar with jboss). If the problem is what you describe, I doubt there is a way to make this multithreading since you would have to commit at the very end of all transaction. You could get it working in multiple threads using the synchronized statement, but then it would not run concurrently. I would just wait for a more experienced person in JBoss to come and help you. I am sure there is an API call that allows multithreading.

Comment: Have a look here in section 2.4: http://docs.jboss.org/jbosstm/5.0.0.M1/guides/development_guide/ch02.html It seems transaction manager is the one you want to use if you want to utilize multi threading.

Comment: @Steven You were right about the UserTransaction being new every time. The problem was that if I use too many threads the database connection pool gets overloaded and doesn't allow more connections. So now I need to make the pool bigger and that should fix my issue. That's why I get the org. hibernate. exception. GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection Error. In any case I will implement your advice and I will be using ExecutorService and the Transaction Manager. Thank you.